# Ruby on Rails - MySQL Incorrect String Value

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using MariaDB with Ruby on Rails 5. I got an error for the first time today indicating a invalid character. You can't see it, but there is a zero width space between the "-" and "I" in the error below. I was able to replicate the issue by submitting my form with the same text. I'm not sure how to fix this. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value: 
'\xE2\x80\x8BDEI...' for column 'address_line_two' at row 1: UPDATE 
`cart_addresses` SET `address_line_two` = 'D/6: JES - ​IEARO​'
```

Comment: The query looks fine.  What is the width of the `address_line_two` column?  Are you sure that this is the actual query which caused the error?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, positive. Between the - and I in the user input data, there is a zero width space that is giving MySQL the error that I posted in the question. It looks to me like a decoding problem but I am not quite sure how to fix the issue.

Comment: What is the encoding of the table?  Could you make it UTF-8?  As an alternative, can you scrub away those unicode characters?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your mysql does not support full Unicode. Should work if you update your encoding settings for the table like below.

```
ALTER TABLE cart_addresses CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8
```

Comment: Will this change the encoding of previously saved text or just new records?

Comment: This is a production site with a ton of data.